# How do I ensure efficiency when using partial application in pure Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have some code that has structure equivalent to this:

```
import Debug.Trace

newtype SomeExpensiveHiddenType = SCHT Double

expensive :: Double -> Double -> SomeExpensiveHiddenType
expensive a b = SCHT $ trace "call expensive" (*) a b

cheap :: SomeExpensiveHiddenType -> Double -> Double
cheap (SCHT x) c = trace "call cheap" (+) x c

f1 :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
f1 a b c = let x = expensive a b in cheap x c
```

i.e. `f1` is a function that computes an expensive result based upon the first two arguments, and then uses this with the third argument. I had hoped that a partial application on the the first 2 arguments, then repeated application of the 3rd argument would result in the expensive computation only being run once. Unfortunately this is not the case:

```
test1 = do
    putStrLn "test 1"
    let p = f1 2 3
    print (p 0.1)
    print (p 0.2)
    print (p 0.3)
```

results in:

```
*Main> test1
test 1
call cheap
call expensive
6.1
call cheap
call expensive
6.2
call cheap
call expensive
6.3
*Main>
```

I've come up with what seems to be a solution:

```
newtype X a = X { unX :: a }
f2 :: Double -> Double -> X (Double -> Double)
f2 a b = let x = expensive a b in X (cheap x)

test2 = do
    putStrLn "test 2"
    let p = unX $ f2 2 3
    print (p 0.1)
    print (p 0.2)
    print (p 0.3)
```

resulting in:

```
*Main> test2
test 2
call cheap
call expensive
6.1
call cheap
6.2
call cheap
6.3
*Main>
```

But this seems quite messy. Is there a cleaner way I can avoid the redundant calls to the expensive calc?

Comment: Also, don't test such things in ghci, compile with optimisations. In simple cases like this, GHC will then share `p` even with the original definition of `f1`. (But you should use dbaupp's advice nevertheless, in more complicated situations, the compiler may not be able to introduce the sharing itself.)

Comment: I consciously used ghci here, as relying on optimisations seems dangerous. The runtime of the real program will differ by a order of magnitude if the sharing is not discovered.

Comment: Right, you shouldn't (blindly) rely on optimisations. That's why I said you should follow dbaupp's advice. Nevertheless, if you want to know how your code will behave, there's no substitute for actually testing your code. The code you're testing in ghci is different, it can have completely different characteristics than the real code. GHCi is great for testing correctness, but neither for speed nor memory usage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just put the third argument inside the `let`, so that `x` is shared.

```
f2 a b = let x = expensive a b in \c -> cheap x c
```

(In this case `f2 a b = let x = expensive a b in cheap x` works too.)

---

What you are looking for is compiler-driven [partial evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation), and that is a hard problem... at least it is sufficiently hard to implement properly that it isn't in GHC.

Comment: (That was quick!) I confirm that does indeed solve my problem. Until now,  I would have considered my f1 and your f2 to be equivalent. I'll need to keep this transform in mind in future whenever I write functions intended to be partially applied.

Comment: @timbod your `f1` is `\a->\b->\c-> let x=expens a b in cheap x c`, and the `f2` here is `\a->\b->let x=expens a b in \c-> cheap x c`. Which by *eta-reduction* is `\a->\b->let x=expens a b in cheap x` (here too). Which is exactly equivalent to *your `f2`*, :) there's not even any boxing involved because `newtype` is eliminated at compile-time. `newtype` is usually used to allow for alternative `instance` implementation of some typeclass or some type trickery. To *float* that *let* `x=expens a b` above `\c->` *lambda* is a bold move, tough 4 _a compiler_ to decide whether it is worth it or not.